# I try to add SEZ Invoice in intrastate using interstate tax code using DI API in SAP B1, but i am getting error select tax code for intrastate B1

Tags: c#, .net, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I am trying to add invoice using DI/API for SEZ unit , As per SAP it takes IGST taxcode (Interstate) but when i am going to add through DI/API with above Showing in code but SAP throws error for Select (SGST+CGST) taxcode. 
Code is available here

```
 SAP_Invoice.TaxExtension.ImportOrExport = BoYesNoEnum.tYES;
 SAP_Invoice.TaxExtension.ImportOrExportType = SAPbobsCOM.ImportOrExportTypeEnum.et_IpmortsOrExports;
 SAP_Invoice.TaxExtension.PortCode = "PortCode";
 SAP_Invoice.TaxExtension.BillOfEntryDate = objCommon.ConvertStrToDateTime(objMCustomerSAP.PostingDate);
 SAP_Invoice.TaxExtension.BillOfEntryNo = "1234";
```

Comment: I am trying to add invoice using DI/API for SEZ unit , As per SAP it takes IGST taxcode (Interstate) but when i am going to add through DI/API with 
above Showing in code but SAP throws error for Select (SGST+CGST) taxcode.